# How do I use latexmk with MuPDF as the PDF previewer?

Tags: latex, pdf-reader, pdflatex

MuPDF doesn't support automatic reloading. How do I use it as a document previewer for [`latexmk`](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/)<sup>1</sup>?

**1:** Example call: `latexmk -pdf -pvc doc.tex`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to specify `$pdf_update_method = 2` in the configuration file, which tells `latexmk` to send a SIGHUP signal to the process when a change is detected:

```
$pdf_update_method = 2;
$pdf_previewer = 'mupdf';
```

Comment: On Linux, you can put those settings into: `$HOME/.config/latexmk/latexmkrc`

Comment: On 18.04 I had to use `$HOME/.latexmkrc`, it doesn't pick up on the `.config` directory.

Answer (score 3):

1. Configure `latexmk` for your user in the file `~/.config/latexmk/latexmkrc` (per [the XDG specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)) containing `$pdf_previewer = "mupdf"`.
2. Specify the configuration's path:

```sh
latexmk -pdf -pvc -r ~/.config/latexmk/latexmkrc doc.tex
```

The default location for a user's configuration `latexmk` is either `~/.latexmkrc` or `~/latexmkrc`.